# WPF XAML Designer adds new column instead of resizing existing one

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the WPF Grid shown below:

[image]

When I grab and drag to right the vertical splitter between the two columns, the XAML Designer adds a third column instead of expanding the left column, as shown below:

[image]

Adding a new column is not what I want.  Is there a way to simply resize a column?

Comment: Personally I would never edit my UI using the designer. The results will never be good. Code it by hand, its much easier. It might have added a new column because you had the Width of the first column set to Auto.

Comment: @GlenThomas I use the UI designer only to get an overall visual picture.  This was one case where I thought I'd give it a try, and it failed me, so I agree w/ you.

Comment: The "visual" designer is woeful. Mine added a new column 9 pixels wide and set all my labels to column span 2 without warning.